# Variable initialization in functions

Tags: c++, function, variables

The variable `days` will not carry over throughout the function. I get an error saying that `days` isn't initialized in the `highest` and `lowest` functions and I have no idea how to fix it. Here's the code that I have so far.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
float temptotal = 0;
float averagetemp = 0;
float temperatures[50];
float average();
void highest();
void lowest();
int main()
{
average();
highest();
lowest();
}
float average()
{
    float days = 0;
    cout << "Enter the number of days: ";
    cin >> days;
    if (days > 50)
    {
        cout << "You may only enter temperatures for 50 days." << endl;
        return 0;
    }
        for (int i = 1; i <= days; i++)
        {
            cout << "Enter the temperature for day number " << i << ": ";
            cin >> temperatures[i];
            temptotal += temperatures[i];
            return temperatures[i];
        }
            averagetemp = temptotal / days;
            cout << "The average temperature is: " << averagetemp << endl;
}
void highest()
{
    float max = -9999999999999;
    for (int i = 0; i < days; i++)
    {
        if (temperatures[i] > max)
            max = temperatures[i];
        cout << "The highest temperature is: " << max << endl;
    }
}
void lowest()
{
    float min = 9999999999999;
    for (int i = 0; i < days; i++)
    {
        if (temperatures[i] < min)
            min = temperatures[i];
        cout << "The lowest temperature is: " << min << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: The scope of local variables is not global.

Comment: Pass `days` as a parameter.

Comment: Your problem description is unrealistic. You will not get an error stating it is "uninitialized". You will get an error stating it is undeclared, i.e. completely unknown. Variables declared locally in one function are not supposed to be visible or accessible in other functions. So, your code, as written, has no chance to work. You have to redesign it. You have to manually pass that variable (that value) from one function to another, or make it global.

Comment: Don't use global variables. Don't use arbitrarily large sentry values in your algorithms like that. There is std::max_element and related functions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass `days` to `highest()` and `lowest()`. If it's a common parameter for all 3 functions, you could set its value in `main()`, and then pass it to them. And I think `days` should be an `int` from your usage of for loop, so:

```
int main()
{
    int days = 0;
    cout << "Enter the number of days: ";
    cin >> days;

    average(days);
    highest(days);
    lowest(days);
}

float average(int days)
{
    ... ...
}
void highest(int days)
{
    ... ...
}
void lowest(int days)
{
    ... ...
}
```